# Augment Registration Model

Tags: identityserver4

I've been looking at the latest version of identity server with .net core 2.2 and I have a general question about the registration model.
  At the moment, the default account controller provides pretty much everything I need out of the box.  Unfortunately, I have a small requirement to augment the registration model to include a registration code that the user must know in order to register.  This could be further augmented with a recaptcha code.  Can you override the one individual registration endpoint or would I have to build my own account controller with all the standard endpoints i.e. forgot password, change password etc. endpoints.  Also, is there a way to get swagger to output the details about the endpoints that are provided through the identity account controller?

Cheers
Mark

Comment: You can pretty much do what you like, the quickstart just gives you a working app to get you up and running. IdentityServer4 itself (i.e. the OpenID Connect implementation) doesn't care where your user data is or how it gets there.

Comment: Hi mackie, we have built a number of server solutions using Identity Server but most times we add our own account controller.  What I'm trying to clarify is can you override one individual controller method without having any knock on effects on the other ones.  If possible, I don't want to have to replace/rewrite all the methods that are already provided by default.  Does this clarify the question?